# How to capture Table Name of failed or success Mapping Configuration task into Snowflake Table using IICS?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

I am trying to log the errors that occurs during loading the data into `Snowflake` table, and my table name is log_table. In this table,I have column, IICS_status,IICS_ERRORS and Table_Name. I would like to capture the `Snowflake` table name where data is getting loaded along with any `IICS` error that are encountered during the mapping. To capture IICS Warning and Status, I referred to this [article](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/533638?language=en_US).

Basically, Data Task 1 is the MCT which is loading the data to `Snowflake`, and Data Task 2 is capturing the IICS status and other information into log_table. I am able to successfully capture IICS status and IICS Error into `Snowflake`. However,I am struggling with how to capture the Snowflake table name into log_table?

I am new to `IICS` so any help on this topic will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There was a trick back in PowerCenter, which is the backbone of IICS Data INtegration, that did let you refer to stats per target or source. Basically it worked like this example, where you refer to some property of your target prefixed with `$PM`:

```
$PM<TARGET_NAME>@TableName
```

More can be found in this [article](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html).

The thing is I'm not able to verify right now if this is possible in IICS. Would you be able to?

Comment: @Maciejg..Thank you. I did saw above mentioned article in other Snowflake question as well. I will dig more if it's possible into IICS.